# Value Count for Droppable (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, count

I am creating a question type for a survey.

I am using the below jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hP3jc/

What i need is a counter or something alike that will let me know how many of the red blocks are being dropped onto the bottom gray blocks.

eg. Strongly Agree = 2 (when 2 red are dropped onto it)
Agree = 1 (when 1 red block is dropped onto it) etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you drop a red box, can you get the class of the grey box?

what i'm thinking is that you can add the class of the grey to the class of the red and then simply do a count of all reds with a particular grey in its class.

so class="red1"  and after drop class="red1 grey2".

when you pick up a red that has "grey" in it's class, then you need to remove the grey class names.

i know i didn't reference any code but i was just thinking of the concept rather than actual code.  I can have a go if you wish though.

so the process i think would be as follows.

setup:
Grey box class has extra class like class="GreyBox Grey1" and class="GreyBox Grey2"

on drop:

- Get second class of the grey box you dropped on.
- Add that class to the Red box you just dropped.
- jQuery to get count `$('.Grey1').length`

on pick up off grey

- Get class of red box
- remove all classes that begin with "Grey"
- re count the reds with grey class names.

Comment: That does make sense, but seeing as I am not 100% great with jquery, wouldnt know exactly where to start! if you can provide some sort of simple jquery that will calculate this for me usiing your example, i should be able to apply it to my code! thanks!

Comment: i have to go home now so i hope someone else can fill in that info.  you could look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ and the stop event.  that will get you the element dropped on.  from there research a few jquery things like "jquery get second class", "jquery add class" and "jquery remove class".  sorry i can't help further tonight.

Comment: @user979517 You will probably have a greater chance of other people helping if you unaccept griegs' answer for now, so they know there is still work to be done.

Comment: @user979517 i have to agree with GregL unless of course you now have the solution